# i am new to ios programming. i m looking sloution for this prblem from many days.. i would be grateful if anyone help me

Tags: swift

thanks in advance 
[here is the image which will help you understanding  my problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KmVzF.png)

there is menu button where "Back" is written.
i want to implement  slide menu on RecordsVC. tableViewController will be sliding menu, slide menu will contain EditContact, Download Records, Settings.. what should be the exact navigation flow. where should i push segue from RecordsVC... i know where to set "sw_rear" segue and "sw_front" segue from SWRevealViewController.. m just asking where to push the segue after RecordVC...
how to connect RecordVC and SWRevealViewController

update and Download are buttons which takes to addUpdateVC and DownloadVC simultaneously.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KmVzF.png)
i hope i would be clear this time.
take a look at image what should i do

Comment: Please describe your issue more detailed and post actual images, not links.

Comment: viewController in centre is SWRevealVIewController

Comment: Capital letters aren't an inconvenience for you, they're a convenience for people you'd like to read your post.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand correctly you are trying to go from Menu to View Controller so you have to create a new segue from Menu View Controller (TableViewController) to View Controller whatever you want then click on segue then go to **"Attributes"** section set the Segue Class to **"SWRevealViewControllerSeguePushController"**:

[image: Setting Segue]

Then on Menu View controller call

```
performSegue(withIdentifier: "goToFavorites", sender: item)
```

If you want to go a View Controller directly from front view controller use this code:

```
let vc = MyViewController() // init this from storyboard
self.revealViewController().setFront(vc, animated: true)
```